# Azure - Consume Event Hub to DocumentDB (not Storage Account)

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have two services running on Azure. An [Event Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-create) and a [CosmosDB/DocumentDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-develop-documentdb-dotnet) database.
My goal is two wire the two with a WebApp service so everything that gets on the Event Hub is consumed and properly stored on the database.

I went through the [Quick Starts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-standard-getstarted-receive-eph) and the Tutorials of both Event Hubs and CosmosDB and I cannot figure out a way of wiring the two.

I know how to establish a connection with DocumentDB, I know how to consume the data of an Event Hub, but I can't manage to do both. Here is the deal:

To create an Event Hub Processor Host I've only found the following constructor

```
public EventProcessorHost(string eventHubPath, string consumerGroupName, string eventHubConnectionString, string storageConnectionString, string leaseContainerName)
```

with `storageConnectionString` being a combination of two strings called `StorageAccountName` and `StorageAccountKey` on the official tutorial.

Well that's actually my problem, Storage Account is another service available on Azure. I've created one for testing purposes and it works just fine but, **I need to store everything on a DocumentDB CosmosDB database**.

I am not excluding the possibility that going through a Storage Account is required, but if that's so, could you tell me why?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you considered setting up a Stream Analytics job and copying everything in that? Depending on the level of processing you need before inserting the eventhub message into the document store, it might be enough, and its a simple solution.

Comment: No haven't had a look at that solution, thanks for sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Event Hub Processor requires connection information for Azure Storage for lease management and check-pointing purposes. Practically this means that if you have multiple instances of your processor running together all the hard work of figuring out who is reading from which Event Hub partitions is completely managed for you.

The EventProcessor class is extremely generic. You just subclass it and then implement `public override Task HandleEventData(IEnumerable<EventData> data)`. Inside this method you're free to write EventData into Cosmos or do anything else your heart desires with the messages coming off of the Event Hub. For example:

```
class CosmosEventHubProcessor : EventProcessor
{
    private DocumentClient _documentClient;

    public CosmosEventHubProcessor()
    {
        // Initialize DocumentClient
    }

    public override Task HandleEventData(IEnumerable<EventData> data)
    {
        // Write data to Cosmos using DocumentClient
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! What you mean is that I need to keep a Storage Account service running so it can do the stuff you talked about, but still store everything in my Cosmos db? I thought the Storage Account service was actually to store files and other things in it

Comment: Yes, you require a storage account in order for the EventProcessorHost to keep track of leases and checkpoints. Azure Storage actually encompasses several different offerings including blobs (file storage), table (simple DB rows), and queues. In this case Table Storage is used for storing lease information. The cost of running Azure Storage for this use case is extremely cheap (pennies per month)